# Simple HTML Javascript button onclick function not working

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, onclick, buttonclick

So essentially I want to keep this as simple as possible, meaning no jquery or bootstrap etc... just straight javascript, HTML and CSS. This is what I have so far

Javscript:

```
var menuOptions= document.getElementsByClassName("nav");

var hamburger= document.getElementById("nav-btn");

  function myFunction() {

hamburger.onclick= menuOptions.style.visibility= 'visible';

}
```

HTML:

```
<HTML>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">  
    <span id="nav-btn">
      <image src="Menugreen.png" alt="collapsable menu"/>  
    </span>
  </button>  
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="Programs"> <a href="Programs.html"> Programs </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="Tshirts.html"> T-Shirts </a> </li>
    <li id="About"> <a href="About.html"> About </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</HTML>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Besides just giving me a solution I would highly appreciate it if you could explain why my current method does not work and why yours does. Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what do you need the hamburger for?

Comment: before I established a variable hamburger but have recently realized I don't need to... but I can't seem to get rid of this error in my HTML "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick". Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few reasons why your current setup does not function:

- `Document#getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, and you are treating the result like a DOM element. You need to access an index like `[0]` to get an actual element.
- Your toggle button only works one way, because `visibility` is set to `visible` but never set back to `none` when clicked again.
- In `myFunction`, `hamburger.onclick` should not be assigned to the expression you chose. I am not sure why you tried to assign another click handler, but in order to make that work you would have needed to set it to a `function () { ... }`.

Now for my advice:

- Use CSS classes to control whether the menu is hidden or not, rather than messing around with the `style` property in your JS. You can use the `classList` property of DOM elements to `.add()`, `.remove()`, and `.toggle()` a specific class when `myFunction` is run. I have chosen to use `toggle` because I think that most suits your use case.
- Use `element.addEventListener` instead of HTML attributes like `onclick`.

### Snippet:

```js
var menuOptions = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0]

var hamburger = document.getElementById("nav-btn")

hamburger.parentNode.addEventListener('click', function myFunction() {
  menuOptions.classList.toggle('hidden')
})
```

```css
.nav.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button>  
    <span id="nav-btn">
      <img src="Menugreen.png" alt="collapsable menu"/>  
    </span>
  </button>
<div class="nav hidden">
  <ul>
    <li id="Programs"> <a href="Programs.html"> Programs </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="Tshirts.html"> T-Shirts </a> </li>
    <li id="About"> <a href="About.html"> About </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm still having trouble because unfortunately I am getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" Do you have any idea why this might be? (it is referring to the HTML)

Comment: Try using `addEventListener` as I have shown in the updated snippet above. Hope that helps! Let me know if it doesn't; post your full code and I can take a look to diagnose the error.

Comment: I really appreciate trying to help me out, but I seem to be getting the same error. I would be willing to send you all my code (lot more than what was given)... is there anyway I can give it to you privately?

Comment: Actually, just create a JSFiddle or Codepen and send the link to me that way. That would probably be easiest.

Comment: The demo is working for me; I removed a stray slash that was closing one of your `div` elements prematurely. I think the error was caused by not removing the `onclick` attribute (you don't need it after you add the event listener a different way).

Comment: Yes! It us working now on the website, can you tell me where it was though (which div) so I can fix it on Sublime

Comment: This person helped me vigorously and went above and beyond; helping me with multiple problems that arose and generously lending TWO HOURS of their time to help me. This is the best support I have ever received from any one person. Thank you so much gyre!!!

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. `getElementsByClassName()` returns a list, not a single element (though the list may contain just a single element), and that list doesn't have a `.style` property. You can use `menuOptions[0]` to access the first (and in this case only) element in the list.
2. You don't want to say `hamburger.onclick=` inside your function, because that would be assigning a new `onclick` handler but your function is already being called from the `onclick` attribute of your button. (Also, if you were trying to assign a new click handler you'd want `hamburger.onclick = function() { /* something */ }`.)

So the minimum change to your existing code to get it to work would be to change this line:

```
hamburger.onclick= menuOptions.style.visibility= 'visible';
```

...to this:

```
menuOptions[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
```

In context:

```js
var menuOptions= document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
var hamburger= document.getElementById("nav-btn");

function myFunction() {
  menuOptions[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
.nav {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">  
    <span id="nav-btn">
      <image src="Menugreen.png" alt="collapsable menu"/>  
    </span>
  </button>  
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="Programs"> <a href="Programs.html"> Programs </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="Tshirts.html"> T-Shirts </a> </li>
    <li id="About"> <a href="About.html"> About </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</HTML>
```

If you want repeated clicks on the button to toggle the menu display on and off then you can test the current visibility:

```
  menuOptions[0].style.visibility =
    menuOptions[0].style.visibility === 'visible' ? '' : 'visible';
```

Expand the following to see that working:

```js
var menuOptions= document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
var hamburger= document.getElementById("nav-btn");

function myFunction() {
  menuOptions[0].style.visibility =
    menuOptions[0].style.visibility === 'visible' ? '' : 'visible';
}
```

```css
.nav {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">  
    <span id="nav-btn">
      <image src="Menugreen.png" alt="collapsable menu"/>  
    </span>
  </button>  
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="Programs"> <a href="Programs.html"> Programs </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="Tshirts.html"> T-Shirts </a> </li>
    <li id="About"> <a href="About.html"> About </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Ok thank you so much for the speedy response!!! I understnad reasoning #2 but not quite #1 (Still unsure what [0] does). Nevertheless, when I changed the javascript code I got this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" This is referring to the HTML, do you know why?

Comment: How do you include the Javascript in your page? The square brackets lets you access an element of a list or array. The 0 is because the element indices start at zero, so `[0] ` is the first element, `[1]` is the second (if there is a second), etc. You don't have to do that with your other variable because `getElementById()` returns exactly one element, not a list.

Comment: What do you mean how do I include Javascript? I use <head><script src="example.js"></script></head> I apologize in advance if this is frustrating, I have only been coding for two months now.

Comment: I mean that your question did not mention or show whether the script was inline, or from an external script, or where the `<script>` element was in relation to other elements. Anyway, if it is in the `<head>` as per your comment, and the file actually exists and is loaded (does it show as loaded in the browser's dev tools' network tab?) and the code is as shown then I can't explain why it doesn't work. (You can see that my code *does* work in the little snippets...)